# Define prev_ds in manual trigger

Tags: airflow

Currently my DAG utilizes the {{ prev_ds }} variable.
I would like to trigger a DAG run manually. However when I trigger manually from the UI with an execution date of '2021-12-14' the {{ prev_ds }} value gets set to '2021-12-14'. Is there a way through the UI or CLI to set that value appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

When manually triggering DAG prev_ds == next_ds == ds ( see [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#why-next-ds-or-prev-ds-might-not-contain-expected-values))
These are the proper values as manual run has no prev and has no next. There is no workaround for this from UI nor CLI.

You can add conditions to your jinja templates to bring diffrent values bases on run type (manual, schedual) but that means code changes.